# All characters after last slash JavaScript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this as a string

```
http://steamcommunity.com/id/user/
```

And when I use this regex pattern : `[^\/]+\/$`  I get this result is

`user/`

I'm trying to negate the last / so i can get

`user`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can't think of any way?

Comment: There aren't any characters after the last slash :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var string = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/user/'
document.body.innerHTML = string.match(/([^/]+)\/$/)[1]
```

I added a capturing group to capture the user folder.

Since that was the `1st` capturing group, I selected the item at index `1` of the returned array from `string.match()`

```js
var string = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/user/'

document.body.innerHTML = string.match(/([^/]+)\/$/)[1]
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45g4pwnw/)

Comment: Ah just saw your edit... thank you. Will accept your answer when the time allows.

Comment: @Garuuk No problem! If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted (press the tick underneath the voting buttons). **EDIT:** Just saw your comment edit, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the capturing group like this `([^\/]+)\/$` and capture the first group using `\1`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rG3sU6/1)

**OR**

Use the `lookahead` assertion like this `([^\/]+)(?=\/$)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rG3sU6/2)

Second method will directly capture `user` without messing with capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks for your input

Comment: @Garuuk: My pleasure. Don't forget to check the second method without using capturing groups.